# C program child process rub again before parent process

Tags: c, linux, fork

I am having trouble using the `fork` function . I would like to write a program that

- spawns four processes
- prints each process's PID, repeats printing the PIDs
- prints the parent's PID

But when the last child process finishes I cannot jump back to the first child process, only print the last child's PID. How can I run the child processes again before the parent process?

```
int noOfPlayer=4;
int pid,myid,status,grandchild;
int i=0;
int a=1;
int x=1;
myid = getpid();

for(i=0;i<noOfPlayer;i++){

    pid=fork();
    if(pid<0){ //error occurred
        printf("Fork Failed\n");exit(1);
    } else if (pid==0) {//child process
        myid=getpid();
        printf("Child %d, pid %d\n",i+1,myid);

        printf("ABC Child %d, pid %d\n",i+1,myid);


        exit(0);

    } else { //parent process

        wait(NULL);



    }   
}
printf("I am parent, pid %d: all children finished\n", myid);
```

The outcome is
Child 1, pid 21989
ABC Child 1, pid 21989
Child 2, pid 21990
ABC Child 2, pid 21990
Child 3, pid 21991
ABC Child 3, pid 21991
Child 4, pid 21992
ABC Child 4, pid 21992
I am parent, pid 21988: all children finished

But I want
 
Child 1, pid 21989
Child 2, pid 21990
Child 3, pid 21991
Child 4, pid 21992
ABC Child 1, pid 21989
ABC Child 2, pid 21990
ABC Child 3, pid 21991
ABC Child 4, pid 21992

Comment: Not very clear to me. Do you have some code to show us?

Comment: What do you mean with "jump back to the first child process"?

Comment: Your output is predictable since you're running your child processes one at a time (parent waits for each one to exit). In any case, you probably want to `wait()` outside the loop. This still probably won't give you the output you expect (because there's no order guarantee between the children, and stdout may be buffered)

Answer (score 0):

When you fork off a new process (or a new thread for that matter), it runs fully independently of the parent and any other children the parent may have forked.  In general, you can't make any guarantees about the order in which the statements will execute.

In order to get the results you want, there has to be some kind of synchronization method between the children.  You could have each child print the first  line, send a signal to the parent, then wait for a signal before printing the second line.  The parent would then wait for a signal from all four children, then send a signal to each one.

It would be cleaner to do this with separate threads instead of separate processes.  In that case, you can use mutexes to synchronize between the threads.

Answer (score 0):

I think I better understand what you are going for now. What you should consider doing is using perhaps a Pipe, or some other form of inter process communication to slow down the processes so that they don't throw everything they've got before you are ready for it.